# Applying an impulse to bullets

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, trigonometry, skspritenode

I have player (`SKSpriteNode`) he can move and rotate, and I want to shoot five bullets from him, but with another angle. I use this code:

```
let sinus = sin(player.zRotation)
let cosinus = cos(player.zRotation)

bullet.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -sinus * 100, dy: cosinus * 100))
```

But, i do not know how to correctly set the vector with angle. I try to make something like this: [image]

Can anyone help me please!

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates? If you were to think about what you need to do as an azimuth rotaation in polar coordinates, you could then at the last point convert back to rectangular coordinates in order to pass to the function

Answer (score 0):

According with this diagram:

[image]

you must change the `zRotation` of your bullets.

Remember that `zRotation` is expressed in radians so if you need:

```
extension CGFloat {
    var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat {
        return self * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI)
    }
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat {
        return self * CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
    }
}
```

To rotate your bullets you can also use (also this one is expressed in radians) :

```
let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 0.01)
```

You can calculate also the speed and the angle of your bullet impulses :

```
extension CGVector {
    func speed() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    }
    func angle() -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(dy, dx)
    }
}
```

If you need you can connect these element with the screen touches as explained in detail [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/57370/trigonometry-game-programming-sprite-kit-version-part-2)

About your comments you can use this formula (already explained in my link):

```
let angle = atan2(location.y - cannon.position.y , location.x - cannon.position.x)
cannon.zRotation = angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
```

Comment: So what i need to do, to shoot my bullets?

Comment: To shooting you could apply impulse as you doing

Comment: I ask how to add angle to impulse